# PHP code changing ownership

Tags: php, chmod, chown

We have a website builder on our website, when client publishes website, there is something in the code that sets up the wrong ownership for folders. What can it possible be? I looked obviously for chown, but it's not there. We have mkdir() and chmod() functions in the code. Can they set the ownership? What else can it possible be?

Comment: They belong to the user which creates them, most probably www-data

Comment: Not sure I fully understand how your service works, they build a website on your site and then you give them the code somehow? Why would the ownership of the code folders matter to them if it is your application that serves the files out to them?

Comment: we have our website on a different server from client websites.

Comment: This is highly dependant on the OS being used. What OS and/or Distribution are you using?

Comment: both servers are Linux based

Answer (score 2):

`mkdir` will create a directory (obviously) and the ownership will be of the user that created it.  For the php script, that will likely be the `Apache` user (assuming that you are using Apache).

Comment: That make sense, but that's not what we want... is there a way to remotely change ownership ?

Comment: There is the chown[http://php.net/manual/en/function.chown.php] that would allow you to change the ownership.  But there are risks with that as you need to be superuser to chown.

Comment: Yeah but chown does not work remotely. The code that executes and publishes web sites is on the different server. I ve seen there ftp_chmod, but there is no ftp_chown

Answer (score 0):

you have to look and for chgrp(), besides mkdir() and chmod(). The PHP process most probably runs under www-data or apache account. Also, it would be very usefull some debugging.